# Why doesn't this printf statement produce the output shown in a book example?

Tags: c, printf

```
int j=5,k=9;
printf("%d...%d");
```

This question was in a book.
output given : 5 9
But when i try this i got : garbage values, please explain this to me.
The explanation in the book says that printf takes values of first two assignments of the program

Comment: Which book was it that taught you that?

Comment: Are you _sure_ the book didn't write: `printf("%d %d\n", j, k);`? If it wrote exactly what you wrote, feel free to stop reading that book and [go get a better C book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)).

Comment: Yes,same thing is written in book,what i wrote above.

Comment: You might want to check if there is an online errata for that book.

Answer (score 10):

Your book authors are relying on *stupid* behavior. (I don't know if it is `undefined` or `implementation defined` or `just plain stupid`.)

They are relying on your stack-allocated `j` and `k` variables magically being there when `printf(3)` is called. Because `printf(3)` will use its *format string* to determine what *types* of *how many* objects to read, it would *magically* interpret the `j` and `k` variables, located on the stack, as *arguments* to `printf(3)`, *as if they had been passed to it intentionally*.

This is relying too much on the magic of "how it all works behind the scenes". Unless this code block is surrounded with "This code might show you ..." and "Never do something this stupid..." then the book is probably not worth reading any further.

Comment: +1 @sarnold I pick plain stupid. This assumption will probably won't be true!

Comment: +1 because I like this version of "book is stupid" the best because you've explained clearly what is wrong with the book's example. Personally, I would call this code `just plain stupid`. It is stupidly dependent on the code generator, lack of optimizer, and calling conventions.

Comment: +1 for making "the book is stupid" convincing and elegant. For what it's worth, this is UB (failure to pass matching argument number and types to `printf`).

Comment: @R.., I _knew_ someone would know specifically :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, if you write

```
int j=5,k=9;
printf("%d...%d", j, k);
```

You will get 5 9.

Now, `printf` is a function that can get a variable number of arguments, it parses the String, which is always the first argument and decide where to put a value from the given arguments. This means that there is no enforcement by the compiler regarding the arguments given to the function and that's why you don't get any error.

If the arguments are pushed to the stack in function call (which is the case most of the time) than `printf` will see `%d` and put the next int on the stack as the number (and so on), since you didn't assign arguments except of the basic string, the data on the stack is not related to the function call (it is related, but it's not what you want :) )

Comment: And even in an architecture where this can work, it is only going to happen if the optimizer is stupid enough to stack allocate and initialize local variables that are not referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Pick up some other book , printf("%d...%d");  doesnt make any sense . You have to supply the two integer arguments to replace the %d in format string .

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int j=5,k=9;
printf("%d %d", j, k);
```

Comment: i know that above will print the answer.but it's not the case.

Comment: In that case get yourself a big stone, a piece of rope, tie the stone to the book and throw it into a really deep lake ;)